# load page in colorbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I'd like to know how do you load a `.php` file into a modal popup made with color box ([colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) is a jquery plugin so you can make modal-dialog popups)?

This is what I want to load

```
<?php include './includes/misc/misc.inc.php';?>
```

into this:

```
<div id="cboxLoadedContent"></div>
```

Any ideas?

My code for the modal popup looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".register_link").colorbox({
        initialWidth:'896',
        initialHeight:'450',
        innerWidth:'896',
        innerHeight:'450',
        fixed:true,
        scrolling:false,
        transition:'none',
        onOpen: function(){
            $("#colorbox").css("opacity", 0);
        },
        onComplete: function(){
            $("#cboxLoadedContent").appendTo("#cboxContent");

            var title = 'Register';
            $('#cboxTitle').text(title);
            $("#colorbox").animate({"opacity": 1});
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can't you just put the include statement inside the div?

Comment: No, because the divs are structured via the colorbox-plugin. My initial thought was how can you accomplish this without modifying the plugin.

Comment: Can the `register_link` href page include it ?

Comment: According to the documentation, you can just provide an `href` key to open any page you want inside the modal.

Comment: @Philippe Boissonneault - No, it wouldn't make sense. This php-file includes parameter-urls like this:
"if ($_GET["task"] == 'login') 
 include 'login.php';
 
else if ($_GET["task"] == 'register') 
 include 'register.php';
 
else if ($_GET["task"] == 'view_message') 
 include 'view_message.php';

else if ($_GET["task"] == 'send_message') 
 include 'send_message.php'; "

etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @drpelz You could add those parameters to the `register_link` url and then you will be able to access them in the `register_link`

Answer (score 1):

Wherever your `register_link` url points to, add the $_GET params with something like [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) or `implode('&', $_GET)`

```
<?php
$my_url = '[url to register_link]'.'?'.http_build_query($_GET);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $my_url; ?>" class="register_link">my text</a>
```

Then in your `register_link` script you can include the file you need wherever you need:

```
<?php include './includes/misc/misc.inc.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out later (but I'm not sure if this will work because I don't have that much experience with PHP yet)!

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work.:( The problem seems to be way more complex than I initially thought. Thank you so much for your help anyway!:)